# wpf double value display

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I get market price Bid / Offer from service , I need to how price as below in XAML

How can I increase size of 3, 4 digit after the decimal

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your decimal to a string. Then split your string into 3 parts (before the third digit, middle part and after the fourth digit) and put those three parts in different controls in the same container control. Change font sizes or colors of your controls as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change size of *decimal*. What you can do is change *presentaton* of that number.

```
decimalNumber.ToString("#.0000")
```

`4` digits after point.